# Should we install lightning arrestor at building when it's between two mobile towers

Tags: electrical, protection, surge-suppression, lightning

I'd like to protect my building from lightning strikes , Hence

neither building and electrical appliances nor people get impacted.

I can see there are two cell phone towers one is 400 metres south from my building and another one is 600 metres north from my building.

If I am not wrong both the towers are at-least 100 feet tall.

By norm all the mobile towers should have lightning arrestor.

Many of my neighbour's discouraged me saying that this cell phone towers should protect the near by 1 km radius.

My building comes in less than 1 km from both the towers.

Is it scientifically right ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a 500ft radio tower 600ft away(reminds me of the friendly giant), so I also looked into this.  It seems high grounded towers are not that much trustful  protection.  They will catch most lighting strikes, but some will miss them.  More of how lucky you feel today situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under an outmoded lightning protection standard, it was thought that objects within a 45 degree cone whose tip was at the top of a lightning rod would be protected. This approach has been abandoned.

Under the [Horvath Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_rod#Lightning_protection_system_design), 46 meters from the lightning rod is all you can rely on because of the nature of how lightning moves in steps. Objects beyond that can be (and are) struck by lightning. So at 400 and 600 meters from the towers, they are not protecting your building

Comment: Makes sense. My building is 80 feet long, 35 feet wide and 30 feet high two storey with open terrace residential building. If I place the lightning rod at the centre of the building , would it cover the whole building including the building walls ?

Comment: @Shravan According to the linked article, if you put the tip of a lightning rod in a place where a sphere with a radius of 46 meters (150 ft) whose center is at the tip of the rod, shall completely enclose the building, it will be protected. I am not an expert in lightning rods. Since this is a major investment, I suggest you consult a local expert, since I know that the path and construction of the grounding cable is also vitally important, as is the specific method of grounding.

Comment: That clears all my doubts , Thanks for your answer.It's helpful